# How to decrease pitch of audio file in nodejs server side?

Tags: node.js, audio, npm, data-manipulation

I have a .MP3 file stored on my server, and I'd like to modify it to be a bit lower in pitch. I know this can be achieved by increasing the length of the audio, however, I don't know of any libraries in node that can do this.

I've tried using the node web audio api, and soundbank-pitch-shift, but the former doesn't seem to have the capabilities of pitch shifting (AFAIK), and the latter seems designed toward client

I need the solution within the realm of node ONLY- that means no external programs, etc., and it needs to be automated as well, so I can't manually pitch shift.

An ideal solution would be a function that takes a file/filepath as an input, and then creates (or overwrites) another MP3 file but with the pitch shifted by `x` amount, but really, any solution that produces something with a lower pitch than the original, works.

I'm totally lost here. Please help.

Comment: What about [this one](https://github.com/mikolalysenko/pitch-shift)?

Comment: @moonwave99 I think that's yet another web-based one, considering it uses WebAudio :(

Comment: Run it in a headless browser then ^^

Comment: Do you have your audio in PCM format ? which is the raw audio curve ?  that is the canonical format from which such tools alter audio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it working with help from [Ollie M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41841422/4624321) and [node-lame](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-lame).

I hadn't known previously that sample rate could affect the speed, but thanks to Ollie, suddenly this problem became a lot more simple.

Using node-lame, all I did was take one of the examples (mp32wav.js), and make it so that I change the parameter `sampleRate` of the `format` object, so that it is lower than the base sample rate, which in my application was always a static 24,000. I could also make it dynamic since node-lame can grab the parameters of the input file in the `format` object.

Ollie, however perfectly describes the drawback with this method

> The drawback to this technique in either case is that the sound will
>   also play back at a slower speed, as well as at a lower pitch. If it
>   is a problem that the sound has slowed down as well as lowered in
>   pitch as a result of your processing, then you will also have to use a
>   timestretching algorithm to fix the playback speed.

I don't have a particular need to implement a time stretching algorithm at the moment (thankfully, because that's a whole other can of worms), since I have the ability to change the initial speed of the  file, but others may in the future.

Answer (score 2):

An audio file is basically a list of numbers.  Those numbers are read one at a time at a particular speed called the 'sample rate'.  The sample rate is otherwise defined as the number of audio samples read every second e.g. if an audio files sample rate is 44100, then there are 44100 samples (or numbers) read every second.

If you are with me so far, the simplest way to lower the pitch of an audio file is to play the file back at a lower sample rate (which is normally fixed in place). In most cases you wont be able to do this, so you need to achieve the same effect by resampling the file i.e adding new samples to the file in between the old samples to make it literally longer.  For this you would need to understand interpolation.

The drawback to this technique in either case is that the sound will also play back at a slower speed, as well as at a lower pitch. If it is a problem that the sound has slowed down as well as lowered in pitch as a result of your processing, then you will also have to use a timestretching algorithm to fix the playback speed.

You may also have problems doing this using MP3 files.  In this case you may have to uncompress the data in the MP3 file before you can operate on it in such a way that changes the pitch of the file.  WAV files are more ideal in audio processing. In any case, you essentially need to turn the file into a list of floating point numbers, and change those numbers to be effectively read back at a slower rate.

Other methods of pitch shifting would probably need to involve the use of ffts, and would be a more complicated affair to say the least.

I am not familiar with nodejs I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-decode, https://github.com/audiojs/audio-buffer, and related linked at bottom of audio-buffer readme.