# How do I change the pitch of an audio WAV file in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I would like to know how I can change the audio pitch from male to female sounding within a Node application. Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

As a start point, check "[How to decrease pitch of audio file in nodejs server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841055/how-to-decrease-pitch-of-audio-file-in-nodejs-server-side)" and [npm/audio-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-decode).